# Default Audio Output Device Selector

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, hdmi

I have a laptop with a HDMI port that I am using at home to connect to a big monitor with speakers.  When at home, I want my default audio out to be HDMI.  However I also take my laptop to work with me so when I am at work I want my laptop to be mute, UNLESS I have headphones plugged in, then the default audio device should be the headphones.
I can manually switch between all these devices but there are still odd times when I forget and either blast the office with my music or be at home and realize after an hour that there is no sound.

Windows seems to attempt to manage the simple rule regarding speakers vs. headphones, but when HDMI is thrown in everything changes.

Is there an application that will allow me to set simple rules such as:

```
On system start:
   If HDMI plugged in, set audio to HDMI
   If headphones plugged in, set audio to headphones
   If none of the above, mute speakers
```

Comment: I think this is more of a function of the audio device drivers, as Realtek drivers seem to be able to do this.  I think it is also part of the Intel Azalia HD audio standard, but I am not sure.  My Asus Xonar STX does none of this.