# Is it possible to setup VLC (or another player) for a proper DD5.1 Output with HDMI? How?

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, vlc-media-player, digital-audio

After quite some struggles with my Audio setup, I decided to create a reference for any other exhausted souls dealing with this.

**Situation:**

Samsung TV connected via HDMI to an ASUS HD7850 graphicscard on a ASUS Maximus V Formula.
The TV is connected via SPDIF to a JBL 5.1 active subwoofer, which has his four satelites connected to him.

Further, there are headphones, connected to the speaker jack at the back.

This setup has it's reasons, there are other possible ways to connect all of this, but this is excatly how I would want it to be - only if there is no way, that this will work, I'll use another, solution.

**Goal:**

1. Using (preferrably) VLC to playback DVDs, mkvs, basically and at best any Video material. If this material has DolbyDigital Audio - play it as DolbyDigital Audio.
2. At the same time, mostly I watch stuff on YouTube or other Streams, where no DD5.1 is available. Then I want to have *simultaneous* audio on my Speakers AND my headphones!

**Sidemarks:**

I am quite annoyed, if I have to setup my audio everytime for 5minutes, even 5seconds, when I switch between watching on the web and watching a DVD or hearing an Mp3. Also there should be no need to differ my setup, just because I want to switch to my headphones.

**Related Questions:**

These Questions helped, but did not the whole trick for me.

- [Keyboard macro to change default audio device](https://superuser.com/questions/426293/keyboard-macro-to-change-default-audio-device)
- [In Windows Media Center, is there a way to use both digital and analog audio simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/440975/dual-analog-and-digital-audio-output-from-htpc)
- [Default Audio Output Device Selector](https://superuser.com/questions/270871/default-audio-output-device-selector)
- [Output Audio via HDMI and Analog Out Simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/484747/output-audio-via-hdmi-and-analog-out-simultaneously)
- [windows-7 hdmi audio](https://superuser.com/questions/92205/windows-7-hdmi-audio)
- [How do I manage multiple audio playback devices on Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/22996/how-do-i-manage-multiple-audio-playback-devices-on-windows-vista-7)

*Extra*

As an extra, because my JBL Subwoofer is a bit older, I always had some trouble when handling DTS Audio - so this would be the special price, when someone could tell me, how to easily make DD7.1 or DTS Audio playable with my DD5.1 speakers.

My last experience was, that my TV handled this conversion good on his own, as long as he had a digital input - but I am not sure on that.

---

Mainly I am searching for a solid solution to playback DVDs, BlueRays, mkvs and other FullHD/NonHD material, which has Dolby Digital 5.1 sound through HDMI as DD5.1 and not as PCM.

So, there it is. I don't know how this could be such a pain in the a**, because one would think, whit the new technologies it should become easier, not more messed up than before.

Big thanks in advance to all contributors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **NOT POSSIBLE** to send a DD5.1 or DD7.1 via HDMI through my TV to my Subwoofer - I will have to use a direct connection or DLNA, or another TV internal source.

From the Manual of my Samsung L37C650:

> When the receiver (home theatre) is set to on, you can hear sound
>   output from the TV’s optical jack. When the  TV is receiving a DTV
>   signal, the TV will send 5.1 CH sound to the home theatre receiver.
>   When the source is  a digital component such as a DVD / Blu-ray player
>   / cable box / STB (Set-Top-Box) satellite receiver and is  connected
>   to the TV via HDMI, only 2 CH audio will be heard from the home
>   theatre receiver. If you want to  hear 5.1 CH audio, connect the
>   digital audio out jack from your DVD / Blu-ray player / cable box /
>   STB satellite  receiver directly to an amplifier or home theatre.

---

My **solution for the second part** with the simultaneous audio playback was this: [How to make Windows Vista/7 output analog and digital sound at the same time - CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_make_Windows_Vista/7_output_analog_and_digital_sound_at_the_same_time&redirect=no)

But I had to change it for my case:

*FIRST:*

- Open Control Panel
- Click "Sound"
- Click the "Playback" Tab
- Right-click "**SPEAKER High Definition Audio**" and click "Set as Default Device" (if the option is not available, it is already
  default)

*THEN:*

- Click the "Recording" Tab
- Right-click "Stereo Mix" and Click "Enable" (if disabled)
- Right-click "Stereo Mix" again and click "Set as Default Device"
- Right-click "Stereo Mix" yet again and click "Properties"
- Click the "Listen" tab
- Check "Listen to this device"
- Under "Playback through this device:" select "**SAMSUNG AMD High Definition Audio Device**"
- Click OK to close Stereo Mix Properties.
- Click OK to close Sound Devices

Also this seemed quite helpful, but was not appliable to my case: [Output on both Analog & Digital at same time? - Windows 7 Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/33546-output-both-analog-digital-same-time.html)

Comment: however, I am happy, if anybody knows a better way, because this just feels like a diry solution, it works but you want to shower everytime you use it ...